# When I try to run Th3inspector tool in termux it is showing error

Tags: linux, termux

- Ihave installed all the packages of Th3inspector tool and since it is written in perl language i type "perl Th3inspector.pl" to run it. But instead it is showing some error that http:: request module not found.

I tried to run Th3inspector tool in termux using the command perl Th3inspector.pl.

Expecting
Th3inspector tool should open listing all its options.

//This is the error

> Results  Can't locate HTTP/Request.pm in @INC (you may need to install
> the HTTP::Request module) (@INC contains:
> /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0/aarch64-android
> /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.36.0
> /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/perl5/5.36.0/aarch64-android
> /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/perl5/5.36.0) at Th3inspector.pl
> line 5. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Th3inspector.pl line 5

Answer (score 0):

You have to run this command in Termux:

```
cpan HTTP::Request
```